# Checking if string is not equal to something is not working

Tags: c#

Why isn't this working? The while loop won't end even when the value of `answer` is `"Y"` or `"N"` (I checked in the debugger) and I keep getting the **Invalid Input** message.

```
        Console.Write("\nYes or No(Y or N): ");

        string answer = Console.ReadLine();

        while(!answer.Equals("Y") || !answer.Equals("N"))
        {
            invalidInput();
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: `while(!answer.Equals("Y") && !answer.Equals("N"))`, notice `&&`

Comment: ANDDDD you need

Comment: Also be careful about case sensitivity...

Comment: @DmitryBychenko shouldn't it be || (OR) instead of && (AND), considering i want the user to pick one instead of both?

Edit: my mistake, it should be with AND.

Comment: If the input was `Y` then `while(!answer.Equals("Y") || !answer.Equals("N"))` means `while(!true || !false)` so `while(false || true)`. It will **always** evaluate to `true`. Always.

Comment: `answer` will always evaluate to not equal to "Y" OR "N".

Comment: Fixed it, thanks everyone.

Comment: You are thinking of Java - @TimvanPeterson. C# doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to *avoid* such errors (`||` instead of `&&`) put it like this:

```
  // StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase - let's ignore case and accept "n" or "YES"
  Dictionary<string, bool> validAnswers = new Dictionary<string, bool>(
    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
       { "Y" , true},
       { "N", false},
       { "Yes" , true},
       { "No", false},
       // Add any other responses here, say {"OK", true}
  };

  Console.Write("\nYes or No(Y or N): ");

  bool answer = false;

  // Keep asking while answer is not valid one
  // .Trim() - let's be nice and allow leading and trailing spaces
  while (!validAnswers.TryGetValue(Console.ReadLine().Trim(), out answer)) {
    invalidInput();
  }
```

Comment: God damn that was fast. +1

Comment: The only thing this doesn't account for is case sensitivity on the input.  Otherwise very nice answer.  EDIT: looks good now.

Comment: @user2366842: I've put `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` (and added the comment) to ensure *case insensitive* correspondence. So all `yes`, `YES`, `Yes` will be valid and mapped to `true`

Answer (score 1):

You can put the two conditions in brackets.
The following example is also case-insensitive.

```
Console.Write("\nYes or No(Y or N): ");
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
while (!(answer.ToUpper().Equals("Y") || answer.ToUpper().Equals("N")))
{
    invalidInput();
    answer = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Good call on the case sensitivity.  That's something that's often overlooked in questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

A string can never be equal to two different strings.  One or both of `answer.Equals("Y")` `answer.Equals("N")` will be false every time.  With `! ||` the overall expression will true every time.

I think you are looking for

```
!answer.Equals("Y") && !answer.Equals("N")
```

Or

```
!(answer.Equals("Y") || answer.Equals("N"))
```